# getting id from jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a `user` bean in jsp. The user bean has a `name` property. I have used the `user.name` as the `id` of `text` element -

```
<form:input type="textarea" id="${user.name}" .../>
```

From JavaScript I am trying to get the id like this -

```
document.getElementById("user.name");
```

but it did not work. Can anyone please tell me how can I get the `id` from JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From javascript I am trying to get the id like this - `document.getElementById("user.name");`

Do you mean you're trying to get the DOM element?  Or do you mean you're trying to actually get the ID of the DOM element, that is, determine what `${user.name}` evaluates to?

If you're trying to get the DOM element you either need to know the ID, or using jQuery, be able to come up with some selector that will uniquely select just the element(s) you want.

If you're just trying to get the value of `${user.name}` in javascript you would want to use something like `var id = '<%= user.name %>';`.

You can combine the two, here are some examples using vanilla js, and jQuery.

```
var id = '<%= user.name %>';
var domEl = document.getElementById(id);
var jqObj = $('#' + id);
var domElFromObj = jqObj.length == 1 ? jqObj[0] || null;
var idFromDomEl = domEl.id;
var idFromObj = domElFromObj == null ? '' : domElFromObj.prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `user\.name` instead of `user.name`

Answer (score 0):

in Jquery escape dot like this:

```
$('#user\\.name')
```

or

```
$("input[id='user.name']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

```
document.getElementById("${user.name}");
```

It write in you HTML render

```
 document.getElementById("demo");
...
...
...
...
<form:input type="textarea" id="demo" .../>
```